# Avoid reserved words 'default' in spring mvc

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I've hit this a couple of times - I'm trying to set a field as 'default' in SpringMVC/JPA & MySQL combination.

The problem is `default` is a reserved word in java, so I tried `primary`, but it's a reserved word in mysql.

I thought maybe I can trick it by storing it with an _ but exposing it via standard getter and setter. But I'm finding the Spring Form UI is not binding the value properly.

Can the code listing below be done and still work with Spring Form tags?  Otherwise can anyone suggest a decent alternative field name, rather than preceding 'default' with an _?

```
@Entity
public class ProductCategoryRelationship extends AbstractAuditable<Customer, Long> {


    @Basic
    @Type(type = "org.hibernate.type.NumericBooleanType")
    private boolean _primary;


    public boolean isPrimary() {
        return _primary;
    }

    public void setPrimary(boolean primary) {
        this._primary = _primary;
    }

    /**
     * Make public
     * @param id
     */
    public void setId(long id)
    {
        super.setId(id);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use the `primary` keyword, then enclose it with [backticks](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/manual/en-US/html/mapping.html#mapping-quotedidentifiers) to escape reserved keyword in SQL.

In JPA 1.0 you can do.

```
@Column(name="`primary`")
```

or JPA 2.0

```
@Column(name="\"primary\"")
```